# Wiring midi sequencers

Tags: java, midi

I need to "wire" two sequencers : player and recorder.
The player may receive midi events from different sources and the recorder will take charge of recording the whole thing to a file.

The following code is just a sample for understanding the mechanism but it doesn't work properly. It will create a file which is quite similar in size and properties to the original but that wouldn't play correctly. The output file is only 3 seconds length and generates only garbage sounds !

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Sequence play, record; 
        Sequencer player, recorder;
        Transmitter t;
        Receiver r;
        try {   
            play = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("input.mid"));
            record = new Sequence(play.getDivisionType(), play.getResolution(), play.getTracks().length);

            player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();
            player.setSequence(play);

            recorder = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            recorder.open();
            recorder.setSequence(record);

            for (Track track : record.getTracks())
                recorder.recordEnable(track, -1);

            // Do some wiring
            r = recorder.getReceiver();
            t = player.getTransmitter();
            t.setReceiver(r);

            // let the show begin !
            recorder.startRecording();
            player.start();
            Thread.sleep(play.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
            while (player.isRunning())
                ;               
            recorder.stopRecording();

            MidiSystem.write(record, MidiSystem.getMidiFileTypes(record)[0], new File("output.mid")); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }       
        System.exit(0);
    }   
}
```

Can anyone pinpoint the problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here, but I'm betting that this will work better if you put the player and recorder in two separate threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even putting the player and the recorder in different threads does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The MIDI file created by the code above contains all relevant events but they are all piled up at tick 0.

Perhaps this is because all tracks in "recorder" are empty.

Anyway, adding a (meta) event to one of the tracks in "record" at an appropriate tick in the future worked for me.

Cheers,
Enzo